# Pass GET parameters with form & Codeigniter to controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I have a html form that his action is for "`exmaple.com/mail.php?name=dan`" for example.

How can I pass this parameter to Codeigniter's controller?

the 'action' in codeigniter is going to - `example.com/mail`, can't I do `exmaple.com/mail?name=dan`, right? so what can I do? (And.. I can't use Ajax for this :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several solutions. You can do it like this `$name=$this->input->get("name")`, but if you want to preserve the Codeigniter's philosophy you can use Javascript to change the action url of the form to /mail/dan. In that case you can access the data with this: `$name=$this->uri->segment($number)`. $number in your case is 2, becouse "dan" is in the second URI's segment.

NOTE: If you use the second aproach, keep in mind that codeigniter's default behaviour is to automatically call controller/method from first and second segment of URI. (http://domain.com/controller/method ) In order to prevent this behaviour you can edit application/config/routes.php file. For detailed instructions refer to [oficial guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

Comment: I forgot that there are segments in Codeigniter. :-) thank you for your right answer and for the others (hidden its nice solution but its not what I looking for..).

Answer (score 1):

You can emit the GET parameter as a hidden input element, i.e.:

```
 <input type=hidden name="name_of_parameter" value="value_of_parameter" />
```

**HOWEVER**, there are two *very* important things to keep in mind when doing this:

1. You absolutely MUST sanitize the CGI argument that you are going to emit on the page (failure to do so can result in XSS vulnerabilities).
2. As with any other parameter, you cannot trust that this value has not been altered (so, don't use 'name=dan' to authenticate dan!).

Since I'm inferring from your example that you are using this to identify and authenticate the user, I strongly recommend you use a browser cookie for this (as well as a digital signature that encodes the checksum of this data, so that if it is altered, you can easily identify that it is invalid).

Answer (score 0):

You should also set querystring variables to true:

In your CodeIgniter config;

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

But keep in mind that this changes the way your codeigniter app behaves. [See more here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

Comment: As of CodeIgniter 2.x this is no longer needed, as GET parameters are now enabled by default with a separate setting, `allow_get_array`.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you simply add a hidden field inside that HTML form and send it along with the form as POST data?

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="dan" />
```

Of course you would replace the value part dynamically with whatever value you currently have.